# Person-centric Assessment - Category list design

Tags: interface, user-centered-design, categorization

I'm developing an interface for an Assessment that needs to be person-centric. The assessment includes several questions grouped into categories. The goal is to keep the Assessors from just going down the list of categories but instead skip around the different categories based on the conversation with the person they are assessing.

The problem in the past has been a simple vertical list of the categories and the Assessors just go from top to bottom instead of focusing on the client's conversation and jumping around where needed.

Any ideas on how to display this list of categories so they can be quickly navigated to, but yet encourage the Assessor to answer based on the conversation?

I don't think there really is a way to do this short of training, but I'm being pushed to find a way so could use your help!

**EDIT** 
This is what I have right now:

```
ASSESSMENT:
Profile
Medical
Environment
Mobility
etc...
```

It's a total of about 15 different categories. Once they are inside a category, they need to be able to quickly jump to the other categories without being tempted to just go down the list.

Comment: Can you add some visuals of how it looks now and/or what you have tried so far?

Comment: Edited to show what I have so far, just a basic list. I haven't tried anything else out yet as I can't think of any other way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

what about a "table of contents" using a box layout where you can have a more broad visibility of the categories than a vertical list. You could also add the page number of that category so users can go back and forth as they change categories.[image]

Comment: This works great as a starting point, but once they are in a category, I can't show this, too much space, but they need to be able to jump around quickly once in a category... Unless maybe a dropdown menu that shows this interface... That has potential.

Comment: so once they are in a category they can´t go back to this page? I am thinking of a jeopardy kind or approach, where they go choosing the topics they are more interested in, once that category is covered you go back to the "table of contents" and choose another one

Comment: Yes I guess that's the same thing I mentioned. Ease and speed of getting back to this screen is a worry as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've provided one potential solution/answer to your question, and that is to structure the list based on the nature of the conversation with the person they are assessing. What I mean by that is that an assessor might start by asking how they are feeling today, which will bring up topics about their medical history. And a typical follow up might be things that they like to do, which will bring up topics around the environment, their mobility, etc.

So this is where you look to the users of the application to guide your design decisions, rather than structuring it around the information that they record (which can only be organized in a sequenced/sorted manner). Of course, which a more flexible grid based design you don't restrict the order as much, but then there's the issue of finding the right area to enter in the information, so maybe you will have duplicate fields in a number of topics that will be filled in already if you covered it in another conversation topic.

Comment: That's the closest possibility I think. To expand on it and see if I understand, it could still have the list for quickly jumping around, but based on what it is they typed, could give buttons below that says "Jump to medical because you mentioned medication" or something like that. This helps thanks!

Comment: @RelicCross That is one way of implementing the approach that I mentioned, and in fact is probably better than what I had in mind originally. I was just going for a basic grid but with a fixed number of elements like UX Research suggested, but which is based on the type of topics that come up in conversation. I think building a smarter search and match interface is a more difficult but potentially more user friend approach.